# Retrieving data for logged in user

Tags: asp.net-core

What is the best way to retrieve data for a logged in user in Api. I can retrieve data for all users just fine.

'ApplicationDbContext':

```
public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

'ApplicationUser':

```
public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

my Repository:

```
public class CategoryRepository : ICategoryRepository
{
    private ApplicationDbContext _ctx;

    public CategoryRepository(ApplicationDbContext ctx)
    {
        _ctx = ctx;
    }

    //to do
    public IEnumerable<Category> GetAll(string username)
    {
        return _ctx.Users.First(...).Categories.Include(x => x.Tasks);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Category> GetAllForFromAllUsers()
    {
        return _ctx.Categories.Include(x => x.Tasks);
    }
}
```

As you have noticed above, I can not use extension method 'Include' on ICollection. 
What is the best way to retrieve data for a specific user?

Comment: Try this _ctx.Users.Include(x => x.Categories).First(...).Categories;

Comment: Ah but you meant multilevel! sorry... Then read this: https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#including-multiple-levels

Comment: Cannot use Include extension method on ICollection

Comment: But you can use it on the DbSet `_ctx.Users` right? or I am missing something?

Comment: I think you are right, multilevel seems to be solution, I am testing that now,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try this?

```
var users = _ctx.Users
    .Include(user => user.Categories)
        .ThenInclude(cat => cat.Tasks)
    .Where(u => u.username == "xx")
    .ToList();
```

From [Loading Related Data](https://docs.efproject.net/en/latest/querying/related-data.html#including-multiple-levels)

Comment: Yes, I have tested, this is exactly the solution, tahnks